# Запуск программы из командной строки

Tags: java

Хочу запустить программу из командной строки Windows. Нахожусь в папке src, в ней есть package - test и в нем нужный класс - Test4. В проекте использую внешнюю библиотеку joda-time.  
Вот команда на компиляцию:

> javac test/Test4.java

Вылетает ошибка:

> test/Test4.java:32: error cannot find symbol
>              DateTime startDate = ...

В чем проблема? 
Я так понимаю, что это связано с той самой joda-time... но как решить проблему не знаю

Comment: Штатный экстрасенс как всегда дрыхнет, так что без исходников никак!

Answer (score 3):

Экстрасенс проснулся и предполагает, что Java не может найти класс DateTime. Так как он расположен в библиотеке joda-time, логично предположить, что последняя не находится в classpath. Попробуйте указать в параметре classpath путь к joda-time.jar. Как-то так:

```
javac -classpath jodatime/joda-time-2.2.jar test/Test4.java
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже сделал